# Octobercm Backend List maximum limit of selections

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I am developing a library system, Octobercms, and I need to limit the maximum number of books for each loan, for example: 2. So that when you reach the number of selections, do not allow me to select more books for that loan.

see the image:
[Backend List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DgVM.png)

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work we need to take `different approach`, `instead adding error when we are selecting` we can throw error `when saving`, (because adding there java-script is little hard as well its client side so insecure).

just add this `code` to your `controller` and `change fields according to need`.

```
public function onRelationManageAdd() {
    $checked = \Input::get('checked');
    $field = \Input::get('_relation_field');
    $maximumAllowed = 2;
    // i have used comment $field you need to replace it with your field
    // this will be your hasMany relational field name
    // also added condition to check selected id is more then 2
    if($field == 'comments' && is_array($checked) && count($checked) > $maximumAllowed) {

        // if selected id is more then 2 we add flash error and return blank array
        \Flash::error('You Can Select Only 2 !');
        return [];
    }

    // ADDITIONAL CHECK if you need more check you can add it here and return error
    if($field == 'comments' && isset($this->params[0])) {
        // currently editing record id.
        $currentEditRecordId = $this->params[0];
        $record = \October\Test\Models\Post::find($currentEditRecordId);
        if($record && $record->comments->count() >= $maximumAllowed) {
            \Flash::error('You Can Select Only 2 !');
            return [];
        }
    }

    // if everything is good then handle request by relation manger 
    //and return response
    return $this->asExtension('RelationController')->onRelationManageAdd();
}
```

I added `ADDITIONAL CHECK` because this will allow user to `select 2 records per one time`, but user can `select 2 records multiple time` but we don't allow them ;)

and you can add `custom validations` you like.

### update

**problem** : select 1 record the first time and then select another record - **solution**

```
public function onRelationManageAdd() {
    $checked = \Input::get('checked');
    $field = \Input::get('_relation_field');

    $maximumAllowed = 2;
    $count = 0;

    // i have used comment $field you need to replace it with your field
    // this will be your hasMany relational field name
    // also added condition to check selected id is more then 2
    if($field == 'comments' && is_array($checked)) {
        //$count += count($checked);            
        $count = $count + count($checked);         
    }

    // ADDITIONAL CHECK if you need more check you can add it here and return error
    if($field == 'comments' && isset($this->params[0])) {
        // currently editing record id.
        $currentEditRecordId = $this->params[0];
        $record = \October\Test\Models\Post::find($currentEditRecordId);
        if($record) {
            $count = $count + $record->comments->count();
        }
    }

    if($count > $maximumAllowed) {

        // if selected id is more then 2 we add flash error and return blank array
        \Flash::error('You Can Select Only 2 !');
        return [];
    }

    // if everything is good then handle request by relation manger 
    //and return response
    return $this->asExtension('RelationController')->onRelationManageAdd();
}
```

**Information:** you can add this `relational field in update context` as when user is `adding new record` that time `we don't have information for current record` as current record `is not saved yet` so `relation count` will **not be available** in **second check** and our `validation will fail`.

**to avoid this issue** you can add update context for that field and that field will only available in `update`.

```
banner:
    label: Banner
    oc.commentPosition: ''
    mode: file
    span: auto
    type: mediafinder
    context: update <------ add this option
```

Now this field will only showed when user save record. and we are now good with our validation.

if you get any error please comment.

Comment: Thank you!
It worked now only allows to select 2 records, but now if the user select 1 record the first time and then select another record it is allowing to select more than 2

Comment: updated answer please try `updated answer` and let me know

Comment: When I create a new record I get an error:


`"Undefined offset: 0" on line 46 of C:\wamp64\www\iepm.dev\plugins\ribsousa\library\controllers\Lendings.php`


`line 46  $currentEditRecordId = $this->params[0];`

Comment: Just put an additional check there , updated answer please check from there

Comment: if($field == 'comments' && isset($this->params[0])) { ...  add this condition as well

Comment: In the update works fine, but when I create a new record and select 1 the first time and then select 2 or more, the validation does not work and continues allowing to add more than 2 records

Comment: then i  would suggest use this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502709/octobercms-validation-relation-user question's answer for validation. it should work for both

Comment: Excellent answer HardikSatasiya , are you in octobercms slack ? i may need your help if you once join in slack please https://octobercms.slack.com/ and search for me with name as @mit and message me once in private . that would be great . thanks