# Octobercms validation relation user

Tags: validation, relation, octobercms

I have the following relation with the user model

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'user' => [
        'Rainlab\User\Models\User',
        'key' => 'user_id',
        'order'      => 'name asc'
    ]
];
```

config_relation.yaml

```
user:
label: Usuários
view:
   form: $/rainlab/user/models/user/fields.yaml
   toolbarButtons: create|link
manage:
  showSearch: true
  showCheckBoxes: true
  recordsPerPage: 10
  list: $/rainlab/user/models/user/columns.yaml
  form: $/rainlab/user/models/user/fields.yaml
```

I am doing the validation on the `user` field, but it is not working, even though I have already selected the user it continues informing that I need to select the user

```
/**
 * @var array Validation rules
 */
public $rules = [
    'user' => 'required'
];
```

Comment: hmm, when you setup this config in back-end form what kind of UI user field shows,
dropdown or list with buttons at top create and link etc ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `I can Understand your problem`. this will occur only when you are going to add new record.

It will work perfectly for `existing record`. as for `existing record` data is `persisted in database` so we can represent a working record and then we can fire `relational validation` on it.

but for `new record` there is no **ID** means record `it self` is **not** saved in database so there will be **no relation with that relational field** so we never know this field has some value attached to it or not and validation will gonna fail all the time.

so no matter how much record you add, it will show `ERROR each time` that "please select user".

October CMS use `differ binding` you can see you can add users without saving current record. as that data is stored in intermediate table so after record is created that `relation data will be transferred to created record` because now it has `it's own ID and persisted in database`.

> **so for solution** you need add validation manually inside that model, with `differed binding scope`.

**First** remove field `user` from `rules`

```
/**
 * @var array Validation rules
 */
public $rules = [
    'user' => 'required' <-- Remove this 
];
```

**Now** we will do `manual validation`

> Add this `code` to your `model`

```
public function beforeValidate() {

    // we need to check record is created or not
    if($this->id == NULL) {

        // CREATE CASE

        // we need to use differ binding scope as this record is not saved yet.
        if($this->user()->withDeferred(post('_session_key'))->count() == 0) {
            throw new \ValidationException(['user' => 'We need User !']);
        }
    }
    else {

        // UPDATE CASE

        // now record is created so we dont need differ binding
        if($this->user()->count() == 0) {
            throw new \ValidationException(['user' => 'We need User !']);
        }
    }
}
```

Now Validation can work for `both case` and you can add different validation for `different cases`.

Now Validation will work properly.

if you still find issue please comment.